# List of interests from Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-marketing-api

I am having difficulty obtaining a complete list of all interests available through the [Facebook Marketing API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis) (or Graph API) for use in my web application. Although I have tried using several endpoints, I have not been able to retrieve the full list.

Can someone provide guidance on how to obtain the complete list of interests?

Comment: I guess the closest would be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences/reference/targeting-search#interest_browse, but even below that they say, that this search will not return _all_ available interests.